# Can't setup OWIN + OneLogin + Bearer

Tags: c#, jwt, owin, openid, onelogin

I'm trying to secure my WebAPI project with authorization tokens. I don't wanna use cookies, I want to only use `Authorization` header like this: `Authorization: Bearer xxx_access_or_id_token_xxx`. I'm using [OneLogin OIDC](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect) as external provider. Here's my `Startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;   

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = "https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/";
    var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OneLoginClientId"];
    var secret = TextEncodings.Base64.Encode((TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OneLoginClientSecret"])));

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] { new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret) }
    });

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);
    app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
}
```

Also I have controllers:

```
public class ValueController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string NotSecure()
    {
        return "Not secure";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public strnig Secure()
    {
        return "Secure";
    }
}
```

Ok, now let's have OneLogin part.
After Authentication Flow, I got 5 fields: `access_token`, `expires_in`, `id_token` which is JWT, `refresh_token` and `token_type`.

Using [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) I can parse my `id_token` and I have something like this:

**Header**:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "xxx"
}
```

**Payload**:

```
{
  "sub": "33827172",
  "email": "john.smith@company.com",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "iat": 1515083928,
  "exp": 1515091128,
  "aud": "onelogin_client_id",
  "iss": "https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc"
}
```

I'm trying to send to my api request with Authorization token. I've tried to send both: `access_token` and `id_token`, but every time I call my secure actions, I've got 401.

How do i fix this?

Maybe here's something I missed?

**Nuget:**

`Microsoft.Owin -v 3.1.0`

`Microsoft.Owin.* -v 3.1.0`

`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` -v 4.0.1

Comment: did you installed `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`?

Comment: Have you checked putting just access_token, in Authorization header without putting 'Bearer' word?

Comment: @talha-junaid, yes, sure. It was installed with some another package.

Comment: You need to debug SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was in Signature.
Here's how I made it work:

```
public static class AuthConfig
{
    public static JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions GetOptions()
    {
        var keyResolver = new KeyResolver(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OneLoginOpenIdConfigurationDomain"]); //https://<your_domain>.onelogin.com/oidc

        return new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OneLoginJWTIssuer"], //https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc
                ValidAudience = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OneLoginClientId"],
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, paramaters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(identifier)
            }
        };
    }
}

#region Helpers
public class KeyResolver
{
    private readonly OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig;
    private static readonly TaskFactory TaskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    public KeyResolver(string domain)
    {
        var cm = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{domain}/.well-known/openid-configuration");
        openIdConfig = TaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await cm.GetConfigurationAsync()).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public SecurityKey GetSigningKey(SecurityKeyIdentifier identifier)
    {
        // Find the security token which matches the identifier
        var securityToken = openIdConfig.SigningTokens.FirstOrDefault(t =>
        {
            // Each identifier has multiple clauses. Try and match for each
            foreach (var securityKeyIdentifierClause in identifier)
                if (t.MatchesKeyIdentifierClause(securityKeyIdentifierClause))
                    return true;

            return false;
        });

        // Return the first key of the security token (if found)
        return securityToken?.SecurityKeys.FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
#endregion
```

And here's `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(AuthConfig.GetOptions());
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

Also I added this to `WebApiConfig`, but I'm not sure that really helps.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
```

**Nuget**:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net45" />
```

In my test [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) with version bigger than 4.0.4 was not working, so leave it like this.

Also I'd like to thanks great manual from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin/01-authorization) and their [Github](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin/tree/master/src/Auth0.Owin.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver).